# Java, How do I put a switch case in a method?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement a getter method in a Triangle class that has a switch statement in it. Usually, I'd write the getter methods one by one for each parameter but I thought I could use a switch statement instead to optimize it.

Usually, it'd be something like;

```
public double getSide1(){
    return side1;
}
```

But like three times for each triangle side. But I wanted to do something like;

```
public double getSide(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1: return side1; 
        case 2: return side2; 
        case 3: return side3; 
        default: System.out.println("Not a valid side.");
    }
}
```

For some reason, it won't recognize the returns in the switch case itself. So I have to add `return 0` at the end. But then the return would be 0.

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Since you added only `System.out.println` to your `default` block there are paths that do not return a value, therefore you need to add a return statement at the end of the method.

Comment: Just a comment on your API, as a user I would rather have separate methods for each side.  Though if you do go with this method, at least rename `n` to `side`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in the default case of your switch statement:

```
default: System.out.println("Not a valid side.");
```

Outputting an error message is not enough.

You must either return some default value

```
default: {
    System.out.println("Not a valid side.");
    return 0;
}
```

or (better) throw an exception when you reach the default case.

```
default: throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Not a valid side.");
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> ... So I have to add return 0 at the end. But then the return would be 0.

If you won't return any thing, then you have one chose, throw an checked or unchecked exception :

```
public double getSide(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1: return side1;
        case 2: return side2;
        case 3: return side3;
        default: 
           throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid side.");
    }
}
```

or :

```
public double getSide(int n) throws IllegalAccessException {
    switch (n) {
        case 1: return side1;
        case 2: return side2;
        case 3: return side3;
        default:
            throw new IllegalAccessException("Not a valid side.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue and to be compliant with best practices to reduce the complexity, it's better to have only one "return path".

For example :

```
public double getSide(int n) {
    int result = 0;  // default value
    switch (n) {
        case 1: result = side1;
        case 2: result = side2;
        case 3: result = side3;
        default: 
           System.out.println("Not a valid side.");
    }
    return result;
}
```